# Calculating the gravitational field on a point mass at central axis of a uniform ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, integration

Consider a uniform ring of mass $M$ and radius $r$ and centre $O$. Let $P$ be a point on the central axis of the given ring at a distance $a$ from the centre of the ring (line passing through the centre of the ring and perpendicular to the radius is known as central axis) such that on joining any point on the ring, suppose $A$, from $P$ the $\angle APO = \theta$ then $$AP = \sqrt{a^2 +r^2}=z$$ Now for finding the gravitational field of ring on point mass $P$ we take an infinitesimal mass $dm$ on the ring. Now the gravitational field on $P$ due to $dm$ is along $PA$ and it's magnitude is $$dE = \frac{Gdm}{z^2} = \frac{Gdm}{a^2+r^2}$$ and net gravitational field due to ring at $P$ is $$E = \int{\frac{Gdm}{z^2}} = \frac{G}{a^2+r^2}\int{dm} = \frac{GM}{a^2+r^2}$$ and along the $X$-axis it is $$E_x = \frac{GM}{a^2+r^2}\cos{\theta} = \frac{GMa}{(a^2+r^2)^{3/2}}$$ Now my question:
Why is this value independent of the central angle of the ring i.e. it should have contained $\pi$ or something which relates to the central angle because if I cut the ring in half then also the field along $X$-axis will be same according to the above equation/formula?
So have I done a mistake in calculation.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: An easier way to find the field strength and not to have to worry about vector addition is to first find the potential which involves scalar addition and then minus the potential gradient gives the field strength.

Answer (score 3):

> Now the gravitational field on $P$ due to $dm$ is along $PA$ and it's magnitude is $$dE = \frac{Gdm}{z^2}$$

This is where you're wrong.

[image]

Now do you understand why?

Comment: +1. Indeed. When integrating over the field, you need to keep in mind that it is a vector and account for its directions in case there's cancelling, as is the case here.  In this particular case, because of the hoop's symmetry, all the $\mathrm dE\ \sin\theta$s will cancel, so you're missing a $\cos\theta$ factor in your final answer.

Comment: @Vega I can't understand what you are trying to explain in the diagram could you please elaborate your answer that where I am wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AdityaSingh See what user256872 told? Did you understand this?

Comment: Yes I saw it but I have asked what if I cut the ring in half, then $dE\sin{\theta}$ will not cancel and also I have applied the $\cos{\theta}$ in my answer.

Comment: @AdityaSingh You cannot simply put $\cos\theta$ after you have completed your integration. You have to put the $\cos\theta$ during your integration. Both give completely different answers. This is your mistake. You should integrate $dE = \frac{Gdm}{z^2}\cos\theta$ instead.

Comment: But according to me these two will be same as $\cos{\theta}$ is not a variable it is a constant as $\theta$ is the angle that the point mass makes with any point on the ring so it is not changing thus $\cos{\theta}$ will also not change and it will come out of integral so multiplying it afterwards will be same as including it before.

Comment: @AdityaSingh You're deviating from what you have to find, you have to find the Gravitational field as a function of distance $a$ along the axis of the ring. So you're integrating with respect to $a$. And cos theta, if you find out, very well depends on $a$. So now try again. I suggest you see any video about derivations like this on YouTube, that will give you a good insight.

Comment: @Vega I think you were unable to get my question correctly actually I don't need the gravitational field of the ring my question is why is it independent of the central angle of the ring i.e. if I cut the ring in half then will it produce same gravitational field ? Well I think it will not because there is mass of the ring present in the equation and it will become half but then $dE\sin{\theta}$ will not cancel as I have mentioned before for the half ring.

Answer (score 0):

"Why is this value independent of the central angle of the ring"
It's because you're *not* integrating over an angle. You're integrating $\int_0^M dm$, wich yields M, plain and simple.
If instead a angular mass density was givem, youi'd integrate over an angle instead, with some factor 2$\pi$ in the result. But that's not how it is stated.

Comment: then how can I integrate using angular mass density as I tried it but it yielded same result so could you please show me your way.

Comment: With $\rho=dm/d\phi$, the mass is $\int_0^{\phi_{max}}\rho d\phi$. That's $M=2\pi\rho$ for the full circle. But again, according to the text that's not what you're supposed to do. You've been given M, not $\rho$.